# XM Cloud local setup error 'nodejs' failed to build

Tags: xm-cloud

I was wondering if someone could help me regarding an issue I was presenting while setting up the getting started template for XM Cloud https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head. When running the `up.ps1` script, I get the following error:

```
Step 6/12 : RUN curl.exe -sS -L -o node.zip https://nodejs.org/dist/v%NODEJS_VERSION%/node-v%NODEJS_VERSION%-win-x64.zip
 ---> Running in fc19214fa4de
hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem fc19214fa4de80f915eefefd035bb83667933368ec746f6e75f831fc1331f2e1: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
ERROR: Service 'nodejs' failed to build : Build failed
C:\dev\sc-xmcloud-demo\up.ps1 : Container build failed, see errors above.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\up.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,up.ps1
```

This is my setup:

Windows 11 Pro
Docker Desktop for Windows v4.16.3 - Windows container mode

- "Use the WSL 2 based engine" is unchecked
- "Use Docker Compose v2" is unchecked

dotnet 6 v7.0.102

node LTS v18.13.0

Comment: You have to activate virtualization on your machine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371378/the-virtual-machine-could-not-be-started-because-a-required-feature-is-not-insta

Comment: Still getting same result. Running the following commands produced the following output:
`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers -All`
->

Path:
Online: True
RestartNeeded:: False

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All`
-> 

Path:
Online: True
RestartNeeded: False

Comment: Thank you @RicharSeal. This got fixed. Turns out the Azure VM was not using a version that supported nested virtualization. Chose the version from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLcBT4LWMS0&t=353s